# what is the meaning of the module.exports = function(app)?

Tags: node.js, express, router

What is the meaning of the codes:All three lines of code.Please explain.

```
   module.exports = function(app){

    var x = express.router();
    var y = express.router();
}
```

Please tell the links to understand these also, as I googled a lot many and read but I have not understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Line 1
module.exports = function()
```

This line means this file has been exported as a function, you can access it by `require('the-path-to-file.js')`.

```
var func1 = require('the-path-to-file.js');
// call the function in other file
func1(app);
```

The other lines is generating the router, the more information is detailed in http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: what is the meaning of the parameter in the function given as `app`?

Comment: It is just an argument of the function.The name of `app` probably means you should pass an instance of express() into the function.